# docker-compose - unable to attach to containers

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

Using below `docker-compose.yml` file if I run "`docker-compose up`" or "`docker-compose up -d`" command then I see both containers status as exited however when I run `docker restart <postgres-containerId>` then its up and running but when I try to run `docker restart <java8-containerId>` then its restarting and again exiting.

Could you please suggest what parameter I need to specify to make these `containers up and running` after `docker-compose up` command and `how do I attach to java container`  I tried with `docker attach <java8-containerId>` command but was not able to attach ?

```
docker-compose.yml file -

postgres:
  image: postgres:9.4
  ports:
   - "5430:5432"

javaapp:
  image:java8:latest
  volumes:
   - /pgm:/pgm
  working_dir: /pgm
  links:
   - postgres
  command: /bin/bash

docker-compose ps results -
       Name                     Command               State    Ports 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
compose_javaapp_1    /bin/bash                        Exit 0         
compose_postgres_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

To see available containers:

`docker ps -a`

To open container shell:

`docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/bash`